# Fortran 90 formatted output

Tags: fortran90, gfortran

I have three arrays, x,y,z.
I want to print these into a file with a character 'C' in front:

```
write(88,FMT1) 'C',(x(i),y(i),z(i),i=1,187)
```

Where FMT1 is defined as:
    character(len=10) :: FMT1='(A,3f12.6)'

When I run the program, I get the following output:

```
C   -1.084900    0.336400    1.074500
I���    0.365700   -3.548800    0.591000
�Ty@   -0.383200    1.417100    3.416700
```

etc.

I am using gfortran in ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must also repeat the character 'C':

```
write(88, FMT1) ('C', x(i), y(i), z(i), i = 1, 187)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
write(88,'(a,3f12.6)') (('C',x(i),y(i),z(i)),i=1,187)
```